# How to initialize state with a counter

Tags: reactjs, arrays, loops, object

I am trying to display in React some characters that are saved in a data.js file.
The first one displays by itself.
The problem is, when i click on the array that i put, the counter is supposed increase and display the next character.

For instance this works, the newCounter increases from 0 to infinite :

```
  let counter = 0
  const [character, setCharacter] = useState(data[0])

  function nextCharacter() {
    let newCounter = data[counter ++]
    console.log(newCounter)  
  }
```

But when i try to initiate the state with the new value, newCounter's value won't increase. It goes from 1 to 2 only.

````
  let counter = 0
  const [character, setCharacter] = useState(data[0])

  function nextCharacter() {
    let newCounter = data[counter ++]
    console.log(newCounter)  
    setCharacter(newCounter)
  }```
````

Answer (score 0):

That's obvious because when the function `nextCharacter` gets called, it calls `setCharacter` which basically updates the state data hence causes a component re-render, and when component re-renders, the value of counter resets again to 0. In order to overcome this, you can define the state for the counter, and update the character whenever value of counter gets changed using `useEffect` hook, something like this:

```js
  const [character, setCharacter] = useState(data[0])
  const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0)

  useEffect(() => {
    setCharacter(data[counter])
  }, [counter])

  function nextCharacter() {
    setCounter(counter+1)
    // let newCounter = data[counter ++]
    // console.log(newCounter)  
    // setCharacter(newCounter)
  }
```

And you don't even need to use the state for `character`, as you can always get that using data array and current counter value. I'm leaving that part as it is, for you to remove.

Comment: Thanks a lot...You solve my problem si quickly...